# Does SDL2 create threads automatically?

Tags: c, multithreading, sdl-2

I'm starting a project using SDL2 to display the result of the [Dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem). I was creating 7 threads for my "philosophers" using `pthread_create` but I've noticed always 5 more threads than necessary using `ps -M`.

Example (with 7 of my voluntarily created threads [confirmed with some text output]):

```
achedeuzot 56774 s000    0.9 U    46T   0:00.04   0:00.06 ./philo
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    48T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           56774         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
```

When I disable the code that generates threads but keep displaying a window, there are still 5 threads remaining:

```
achedeuzot 57751 s000    0.9 U    46T   0:00.04   0:00.06 ./philo
           57751         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           57751         0.0 S    48T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           57751         0.0 S     0T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           57751         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
           57751         0.0 S    46T   0:00.00   0:00.00
```

So it seems that SDL2 is creating 5 threads on it's own. I'm using `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED` for `SDL_CreateRenderer()`.

I have searched for other people mentioning this but couldn't find anything about it (or my keywords were not OK).

Where are these 5 extra threads coming from ? Is it something specific to my computer ? Is it from the GPU acceleration ? Is it from the `ps` command ? Is it SDL2 or some sub-routine of SDL2 ?

Thank you for helping me see more clearly what is happening here !

Additional info: I'm not using `SDL_CreateThread()`. I'm on a Mac, OS 10.9.3.

Comment: So threads are created, regardless of your code?

Comment: It seems so. I would like to know if others have noticed the same thing by using SDL2 or if it's something "strange" on my computer.

Comment: My old sdl 1.2 program creates an additional thread on its own, ( no opengl )

Comment: Is it SDL 1 or 2? Something with the new version?

Comment: It could also be that the thread library creates some of its own...

Comment: @twalberg meaning the `#include <pthread.h>` ? Hmm....

Comment: Not by just including it but some actual calls. Use a debugger to find out what the threads are doing or look at SDL's sources if you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the latest SDL2 sources, a quick grep for 'SDL_CreateThread' reveals

```
src/video/cocoa/SDL_cocoamousetap.m
src/video/winrt/SDL_winrtevents.cpp
src/video/psp/SDL_pspevents.c
src/timer/SDL_timer.c
src/main/haiku/SDL_BeApp.cc
src/haptic/windows/SDL_syshaptic.c
src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi.c
src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi_overrides.h
src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi_procs.h
src/thread/SDL_thread.c
src/joystick/winrt/SDL_xinputjoystick.c
src/joystick/windows/SDL_dxjoystick.c
src/joystick/psp/SDL_sysjoystick.c
src/audio/SDL_audio.c
```

Of those, you're probably interested in cocoa specific and general invocations.  Narrowing in on the cocoa case we see:

```
void
Cocoa_InitMouseEventTap(SDL_MouseData* driverdata)
{
    SDL_MouseEventTapData *tapdata;
    driverdata->tapdata = SDL_calloc(1, sizeof(SDL_MouseEventTapData));
    tapdata = (SDL_MouseEventTapData*)driverdata->tapdata;

    tapdata->runloopStartedSemaphore = SDL_CreateSemaphore(0);
    if (tapdata->runloopStartedSemaphore) {
        tapdata->thread = SDL_CreateThread(&Cocoa_MouseTapThread, "Event Tap Loop", tapdata);
        if (!tapdata->thread) {
            SDL_DestroySemaphore(tapdata->runloopStartedSemaphore);
        }
    }

    if (!tapdata->thread) {
        SDL_free(driverdata->tapdata);
        driverdata->tapdata = NULL;
    }
}
```

So at least one thread for mouse events there.  Perhaps another thread or two for timers and audio as well.

If you really want to know what those threads are doing, by far the easiest thing is going to be attaching with 'gdb -p' and running 'thread apply all backtrace'.

Comment: I only use the video aspect of SDL, no mouse nor audio for the moment. But I'm indeed using the timer. Thanks for this insight !